# Best way to merge multiple large API responses

Tags: php, rest, api, merge, response

I'm trying to get log files from a cloud based SMTP server through a REST API (documentation available on https://www.smtpeter.com/en/documentation/rest-logfiles).

The API only allows me to request log files for 1 day (e.g. https://www.smtpeter.com/v1/logfiles/deliveries.2018-07-17.log/json). A log file for 1 day contains about 10.000 records. However, I want to have log files for a week or even a month. I have contacted the company to ask if they support API requests for periods more than 1 day, but they don't. They said I should make multiple requests and merge the responses myself.

My programming knowledge is limited and my knowledge of using API's is basically zero. But with help of Google (and many other SO questions) I came up with this PHP script:

```php
<?php
// Disable time limits
set_time_limit(0);

// Let's set some variables
$api_key = '###';
$date=date_create("2018-04-02");
$days = [];

for($i = 0; $i <=6; $i++) {
    // Variables
    $deliveries_url = 
    'https://www.smtpeter.com/v1/logfiles/deliveries.'.date_format($date,"Y-m-d").'.log/json/?access_token='.$api_key;

    // Make an array for this day/iteration and put the API response inside the array  
    ${"day$i"} = json_decode(file_get_contents($deliveries_url), true);

    // Add array name to the days array in order to know how many days we need to merge later
    array_push($days,${"day$i"});

    // Add 1 day before starting all over again    
    date_add($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 days"));
}

// Merge all data that we've previously gathered
$data = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $days);
?>
```

So this will make multiple requests with a different date each time and put the decoded JSON into an array. After the loop is finished it will merge all the arrays into 1 big array. It actually works fine for 2 days (about 20.000 records). But when I push the loop to a max of 3, 4 or more days, I'll end up with an empty array (guess it's timing out or something).

I'm guessing this is probably the least efficient way of accomplishing my goal. So please advice: what's the best way to reach my goal?

Comment: Anyone who can help me, please?